# How do I debug a Kubernetes validating admission webhook?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a webhook running as a service in cluster, I have a valid `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` defined for it:

```
    apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
    metadata:
      name: ingress-check-webhook-cfg
    webhooks:
      - name: ingress.check.webhook
        rules:
          - apiGroups:
              - extensions
            apiVersions:
              - v1
            operations:
              - CREATE
              - UPDATE
            resources:
              - ingresses
        failurePolicy: Ignore
        clientConfig:
          service:
            name: ingress-check-webhook-svc
            namespace: operations
            path: "/validate"
          caBundle: <cert stuff>
```

I can `curl -k https://ingress-check-webhook-svc.operations/validate`
within the cluster and see log entries in my webhook service but when I create a new `ingress` I get nothing. I can't seem to find any logs for the admission process - where is this logged, what else can I do?

Comment: [Matt Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4655770/matt-reynolds), `kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` has property `metadata.namespace`. Do you use your new Ingress in different namespace?

Comment: [this section](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.10.0-beta.1/staging/src/k8s.io/api/admissionregistration/v1beta1/types.go#L145) in the code outlines when a webhook will run and it says the default is to run on anything. It was pointed out to me that the `ingress` api version is `v1beta1` so I updated that with no change. I've tried using `kubectl get events` and looking at the api server logs with no success

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here to find out how to debug a validatingwebhook or how to see logs for a validating webhook, you need to look at the the pod that is handling these validation requests.

1. Identify the service/endpoint the validatingwebhook sends requests to, e.g. in this case

   ```yaml
   clientConfig:
     service:
       name: ingress-check-webhook-svc
       namespace: operations
       path: "/validate"
   ```
2. Look for the selectors in the service

   ```bash
   kubectl get service -n operations ingress-check-webhook-svc -oyaml
   ```

   ```yaml
   selector:
     app: ingress-check-webhook
   ```
3. Identify the pods with these labels and look for the logs

   ```bash
   kubectl get pods -l app=ingress-check-webhook
   kubectl logs -l app=ingress-check-webhook
   ```

Answer (score -5):

deleting and re-creating the config seems to have fixed my issue. Maybe I didn't apply the api version change correctly. Note `kubectl describe` `kubectl get events` and checking api logs didn't provide anything useful.